# How do I favorite/hotkey a dual wield setup?

Tags: pc, the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I've been playing Skyrim for a while now, and still have not figured out how to properly create a hot-key to my dual wield setup. I've tested with spells, which easily allow you to select multiple spells or dual wield the same spell. But with weapons, if I use my hot-keys to switch to a spell in my left hand, and then afterwards, hit the hot-key for my weapon, it just swaps the weapon I have in my right hand, keeping the spell in my left hand. It makes it very annoying to harvest souls, as I have to open the Quick menu each time, and manually select it in the proper hand.

Comment: I couldn't ever get dual wield to work properly. What I wound up doing is hit the left-hand hotkey twice, then the right-hand hotkey once. You should end up with things in their proper hands (unless you want to wield a weapon left-handed, I suppose).

Comment: it gets doubly annoying when you are dual wielding two of the same items.  One of them always drops out of the favorites menu.

Comment: I've upvoted the good workarounds, however, I'm not marking an answer since it's obviously a missing feature in the game, that'll hopefully get added/fixed later.

Comment: I think it's bugged. I simply want hotkey 1 to dual wield 2 of the same dagger, and hotkey 2 for healing one handed. No matter how I favorite and setup 1 as dagger or daggers, the game drops it after I switch to healing and try to re-equip my daggers. The favorites menu confirms the 1 has dropped and now there are the dagger or daggers there with no number(s). Pressing 1 twice doesn't work, although it works for dual spell wielding.

Answer (score 9):

What works for me:

1. Favorite the weapons
2. Equip them in the proper hands
3. Assign a hotkey only to the one in the right hand

Now, only hit that hotkey when that's not already the equipped weapon, and you should get both.

If you do accidentally hit the hotkey when the weapon is equipped already, sometimes you'll end up de-equipping the left hand weapon; just hit the hotkey again to re-equip it.

Comment: This has been my solution as well, and works as long as I do it just right.

Comment: Yea... this works for unenchanted items... As soon as I made them magical this trick stopped working. so annoying... why can't they make setups bound to favorites instead of singular items.

Comment: @RaZorHamZteR I use it with a Glass Dagger of Some-sort-of-ice-enchantment and an Ebony Dagger of Some-sort-of-fire-enchantment without any problems - your problem isn't related to the enchantment.

Comment: this trick wont work if you want to have both dual wielded weapons hotkeys and dual spells hotkeys. really annoying...

Comment: Thanks, I was messing with this for a while and wasn't sure how it works. :)

Comment: This works for me https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pCeeG7LJfQk 
Able to group dual wield into a group. (default hotkey F1, F2 ect., which can be changed in Mod Configuration Menu of SKSE). and able to switch to magic spells and then 1 key reverts back to dualwield.

Answer (score 2):

The only scenario in which you can do this is if you have two identical weapons.  Remember that the goal is to be able to switch to your dual wield setup, and that using a spell when dual-wielding will always start off in the off-hand (hitting it twice will dual-cast it).

If you have two identical weapons (so they get listed as Glass Sword (2)), you can set up a favorite and link a hotkey to them.  Hitting that hotkey twice will dual wield the weapons.

Hopefully they'll address the ability to fully hotkey dual wielding at some point.

Comment: My method works fine with two different weapons.

Comment: It works fine if you're switching between Two-Handed or Bow and Dual Wielding.  It does not work if you're using hot keys for spells and trying to switch back to dual wielding.

Setup #1: Ebony Dagger (hotkey 1), Glass Dagger (hotkey 2).  Bow (hotkey 3).  Equip daggers in desired hands. Hit 3 (equip bow). Hit 1 (equip Ebony), and the Glass is still off-hand.

Comment: Setup #2: Same daggers, Flames on 3. Hit 3 (flames goes in off-hand, hit it twice to dual-cast).  Now try hitting any combination of 1 or 2 to equip both daggers.

I think the central confusion here is likely that some are using 2-handers

Comment: I have 2 Falmer swords which used to stack (but then, ...) and worked with 1 hotkey to dual-wield. But since I upgraded both to Superior, this is broken as well

Answer (score -5):

Go on inventory and press F on the items you want as a favorite then press Q whilst playing and press 1-8 for the hotkey you want on the item

Comment: This doesn't answer the core question here of **dual** wielding i.e. two items one in each hand.